# Printing a string in awk

Tags: bash, shell, printing

I have a problem with printing using awk, as I am new to this.

This is the code:

```
nm $1 >file1 
nm $2 >file2
awk '{print $(NF)}' file1 | sort -u >one
awk '{print $(NF)}' file2 | sort -u >two

var1=$(grep -Fxf two one)
```

(The code is finding symbols (functions), which are similar in both files. It saves those strings, which are the same in both files to var1)

All i need to do is take first argument(input file), print it, take second arument and print it too, then print var1, all on same line. Output should look like this:

```
 argument1 -> argument2 (first line from var1)
 argument1 -> argument2 (second line from var1)
 .
 .
 .
 argument1 -> argument2 (last line from var1)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read each line from `var1` and print using a loop:

```
while read line; do
  echo "$1 -> $2" "${line}"
done <<<"${var1}"
```

`<<<` is called [here strings](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would refactor your script:

```
while read -r line; do
   echo "$1 -> $2 ($line)"
done < <(grep -Fxf <(nm "$1"|awk '{print $(NF)}') <(nm "$2"|awk '{print $(NF)}'|sort -u))
```